# Where Paho gets connected to when used with list of brokers

Tags: java, mqtt, paho

How to find out where Paho Java client got actually connected to when it was called with list of severURIs.

I work on a client application where multiple equal brokers are used to achieve “High Availability” system. Paho is provided with list of all brokers to connect to:

```
MqttConnectOptions options = new MqttConnectOptions();
options.setServerURIs( new String[]{"tcp://broker1.com:1883", 
         "tcp://broker2.com:1883", "tcp://broker3.com:1883"} );

MqttClient mqttClient = new MqttClient("tcp://broker1.com:1883", 
         clientId, new MemoryPersistence());
mqttClient.connect(options);
```

After connect I would like to report where it has got actually connected to, but I do not know how. 
`MqttClient.getServerURI()` returns URI provided in MqttClient constructor regardless it is connected to.

According to documentation:

> When an attempt to connect is initiated the client will start with the
>   first serverURI in the list and work through the list until a
>   connection is established with a server. If a connection cannot be
>   made to any of the servers then the connect attempt fails.